# Cannot boot existing Ubuntu as qemu VM

Tags: qemu

I have my normal OS (Devuan) on sda1, Debian 9 on sda2 and Ubuntu 20.04 on sde1.

All OS's boot normal when selected with grub during cold boot.

When I boot up Devuan I want to run Debian and/or Ubuntu in a VM and is using qemu as follows:
`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /dev/sda`
 and then follow the grub-menu to select either.
Debian boots up in the VM no problem, but Ubuntu fails with:

```
error: no such device: correct-uuid-for-sde1
error: hd4 cannot get C/H/S values
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

and then pops back to the grub menu.

To boot Ubuntu in the qemu VM I also tried:
`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -hda /dev/sde`
and get:
`error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found`
and then goes into grub rescue. Doing `ls` in grub rescue does not list `hd4`, only `hd0` (and fake?? `fd0`). trying `set root=(hd4,1)` etc, fails with `cannot load C/H/S values`.

Any ideas on what may be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it - describing what happened for whoever runs into similar problem.

I installed Ubuntu but did not install grub, relying on the grub installed with the Devuan-installation to pick up the Ubuntu-install - which it did, and all seemed to work fine.

Then the qemu-issue: I resolved this by cold-booting Ubuntu and doing a proper install of grub (in Ubuntu), and then back in Devuan did an `update-grub`, after which the qemu-issue was resolved and the VM came up as it should.